# Create ul lists dynamically from one array

Tags: html, angularjs, html-lists, angular-ng-if

I am working with angularjs (version 1), I know it's old, but I need to work with this version.

I have this list

```
products = [
{
    "productID": 1,
    "productName": "product1",
    "productCategoryName": "category1"

},
{
    "productID": 2,
    "productName": "product2",
    "productCategoryName": "category1"
},
{
    "productID": 3,
    "productName": "product3",
    "productCategoryName": "category1"
},
{
    "productID": 4,
    "productName": "product4",
    "productCategoryName": "category2"
},
{
    "productID": 5,
    "productName": "product5",
    "productCategoryName": "category2"
},
{
    "productID": 6,
    "productName": "product6",
    "productCategoryName": "category3"
}];
```

My html code (it's incorrect):

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div ng-repeat="product in vm.products | groupBy: 'productCategoryName'">    
            {{ product.productCategoryName}}
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="something">
                    <label> {{ product.productName }}</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The result I want is to be able to create a ul for every productCategoryName, something like this:

```
<h3>category1</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>product1</li>
                            <li>product2</li>
                            <li>product3</li>
                        </ul>
                        <h3>category2</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>product4</li>
                            <li>product5</li>
                        </ul>
                        <h3>category3</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>product6</li>
                        </ul>
```

I can check if this is true:
`<ul ng-if="vm.products[$index - 1].productCategoryName !== product.productCategoryName ">`

So I can create a new list when the current index has different category, but my problem here is that I cannot control the closing of the list 
I am not sure how can I fix this, would be great if you an help. Thanks!

Comment: The grouping concept is fine. At a new group, create a new <ul>...</ul> It's within the <li> that you will need another ng-repeat. The first ng-repeat will be for the groups, the second ng-repeat will be for the items within that group. Something like
```<li ng-repeat="item in product">{{item.productName}}</li>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of doing it.

```
<html>
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="mycontroller">
<div class="form-group">
  <div ng-repeat="productGroup in groups">
    <div>
      {{ productGroup.productCategoryName}}
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in productGroup">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="something">
          <label> {{ value.productName }}</label>
        </li>
      </ul>        
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
angular.module('myapp', []).controller('mycontroller', function($scope, $filter){
    $scope.products = [
    {
        "productID": 1,
        "productName": "product1",
        "productCategoryName": "category1"

    },
    {
        "productID": 2,
        "productName": "product2",
        "productCategoryName": "category1"
    },
    {
        "productID": 3,
        "productName": "product3",
        "productCategoryName": "category1"
    },
    {
        "productID": 4,
        "productName": "product4",
        "productCategoryName": "category2"
    },
    {
        "productID": 5,
        "productName": "product5",
        "productCategoryName": "category2"
    },
    {
        "productID": 6,
        "productName": "product6",
        "productCategoryName": "category3"
    }];

    $scope.groups = $filter('groupBy')($scope.products, 'productCategoryName');
})
.filter("groupBy",["$parse","$filter",function($parse,$filter){
  return function(array, groupByField){
    var result  = {};

      var prev_item = null;
      var groupKey = false;
      var filteredData = $filter('orderBy')(array, groupByField);

        for(var i=0; i < filteredData.length; i++) {        
        if (!result[filteredData[i][groupByField]]) {
            result[filteredData[i][groupByField]] = [];
          result[filteredData[i][groupByField]].productCategoryName = filteredData[i][groupByField];
        }

        result[filteredData[i][groupByField]].push(filteredData[i]);
      }

      return result;
  }
}])
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8hscydq9/1/

To help with performance, you can create the group ahead of time and then display that group. Otherwise, on every angular digest it will be recreating the group.